# Unable to Deploy Project in Pi 2 , Pi 3 with Windows IOT

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I have been trying for three days to deploy my project in Windows IOT on Raspberry Pi2 / Pi3  with  Visual studio 2015 update 3  with all SDKs and tools updated . This is the error i am getting .

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. Failed to register through new deployment pipeline. (0x80004005)              
Error       DEP8000 : Unexpected deployment failure : RemoteCommandException : Windows cannot install package 5052b388-e89a-4922-830b-b25b6a73ec28_1.0.0.0_arm__rzmxk8cgvfnva because this package depends on a framework that could not be found. Provide the framework "Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0" published by "CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US", with neutral or ARM processor architecture and minimum version 1.0.23819.0, along with this package to install. The frameworks with name "Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0" currently installed are: {}

0x80073cf3              
Error       DEP8000 : Unexpected deployment failure : COMException : The Appx package's manifest is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080204)               
Error       DEP8000 : Unexpected deployment failure : COMException : The Appx package's manifest is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080204)
```

I have tried all possible things .

1. Installed VS 2015 on different PC and tried to deploy there getting same error
2. Tried Windows SDK all versions.
3. Tried two different SD cards and flashed them twice
4. Changed network port
5. Tried sample basic app that comes with visual studio

But still no luck at all .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the problem  i need to have windows 10 operating system